# LinearState with two unconsumed states in Corda FlowTest setup

Tags: corda

I am trying to write a FlowTest for a Flow with a LinearState.  In the setup, I need to create a LinearState and then create a second version of that state (with the same unique identifier) by consuming the first in a second transaction.  I followed the steps in [the v2.0](https://docs.corda.net/flow-testing.html) tutorial on the corda docs.

However, when I query for the states in the vault, I get two unconsumed states.  I would have expected one of them to have been consumed (and thus have `Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED`).

I have written a driver based integration test for the real code, and that works fine. So I'm presuming I have incorrectly set up the test for this situation.

Any ideas what I need to do to have only one unconsumed state in the vault?

Similar test code to reproduce [here](https://gist.github.com/nimmaj/b8b1c7c26fcd76ce110bafd72b3dd387)

Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test code, you generate the two transactions first, then record them both at once using the following code:

```
member1.database.transaction {
    member1.services.recordTransactions(tx1, tx2)
}
```

If you modify your code so that you record the first transaction before the second, the flow tests pass:

```
member1.database.transaction {
    member1.services.recordTransactions(tx1)
    member1.services.recordTransactions(tx2)
}
```

It looks like `recordTransactions` doesn't necessarily record the transactions in the order in which they are passed in as arguments. If `tx2` is recorded first, it can't find the output state of `tx1` to mark as consumed. The output state of `tx1` therefore remains unconsumed.

Comment: Nice one - thanks.  I'll raise a PR to change the docs to reflect this.  Possibly one for the code also.