# Broadcasting an old transaction will cause 2 unconsumed states

Tags: corda

On Corda 3.0 Postgres 9.6.

Assuming there's a `LinearState` in a bank node that has transitioned to

`A lifecycle in Tx1 -> B lifecycle in Tx2 -> C lifecycle in Tx3 -> D lifecycle in Tx4`.

I have a regulator with an empty vault. With the observables concept, when the bank sends `Tx4` to the regulator. Regulator will have unconsumed `LinearState` at `D lifecycle` in `vault_states` - which is good and fine.

If the bank incorrectly sends `Tx2` to the Regulator after the above, then regulator will record 2 UNCONSUMED states of the same UUID at `B lifecycle`, and `D lifecycle` snapshots. Is this expected behavior?

Another scenario

1. If the bank sends `Tx2` first then `Tx4` sequentially, Both `Tx2` and `Tx4` is unconsumed
2. If the bank sends `Tx2` first then `Tx3` sequentially, `Tx2` will be consumed and `Tx3` is unconsumed.

Code snippet below

```
class ReportToCounterparty(
private val regulator: Party, 
private val signedTx: SignedTransaction) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val session = initiateFlow(regulator)

        subFlow(IdentitySyncFlow.Send(session, signedTx.tx))

        subFlow(SendTransactionFlow(session, signedTx))
        return session.receive<SignedTransaction>().unwrap { it }
    }
}


@InitiatedBy(ReportToCounterparty::class)
    class ReceiveReportedTransaction(private val otherSideSession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        // TODO: add error handling

        subFlow(IdentitySyncFlow.Receive(otherSideSession))

        val recorded = subFlow(ReceiveTransactionFlow(otherSideSession, true, StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE))

        otherSideSession.send(recorded)
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like a bug. Can you update the question with the Corda version?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug. It is tracked here: https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-1828.

Comment: Thanks, seems the issue was found before here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645099/linearstate-with-two-unconsumed-states-in-corda-flowtest-setup